# How to customise directe update message on Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I want to show a custom message about direct update of application. Someone knows how can I do it?

Comment: You'll need to explain what's a "perfect message". Please be careful with writing questions like this; the stack overflow community does not have lots of patience towards questions that do not properly explain the issue, so if you want help - better write a proper question. :-)

Comment: Thank you, Idan! I will be more considerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're actually talking about is that you want to simply customize the default provided Direct Update dialog to one of your own, and you're using Worklight 6.2 or later, you can follow the example as provided in the [Getting Started > Direct Update tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-quickly-update-application/), in the [User Experience section](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-quickly-update-application/#userExprience). You can find more in-depth information [in this user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_customizing_direct_update_ui_android_wp8_ios.html).

I also exlpain this in the following related question: [Is it possible to allow Worklight users to use app before updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553545/is-it-possible-to-allow-worklight-users-to-use-app-before-updating)